# Nivo Slider Positioning in Firefox

Tags: css, nivo-slider

I'm at a loss to what might be going on with my Nivo Slider on this page:  [www.wicybertechs.com/jimreif1](http://www.wicybertechs.com/jimreif1)

Everything works great in Chrome, IE, but good-old firefox is pushing the images down further than what they should be.

Any thoughts on where to start?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: _“Any thoughts on were to start?”_ – yes, here: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Change in CSS file:

```
#slider{
    margin: -548px auto auto auto;
}
```

Remove from #slider:

```
clear:both;
```